# How do you print ESLint settings to a local file using Windows Powershell?

Tags: javascript, eslint

I'm trying to use [the eslint CLI](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/command-line-interface) to print `eslint` settings to a file.

When I run this...

```
./node_modules/.bin/eslint --print-config "*.*"
```

... it correctly prints to the console.

But when I run this...

```
./node_modules/.bin/eslint --print-config "*.*" -o "C:\dev\AwesomeLabs\awesome-chat-app\eslint_settings.js"
```

...I still get the full output to the console.

How do I print the output to a file? ‍♀️

Comment: `./node_modules/.bin/eslint --print-config "*.*" > file`?

Comment: Ha! I was over thinking it. That works. Thanks @gman 

Answer (score 1):

#### *Lifted from comment by @gman.*

This does the trick.

```
./node_modules/.bin/eslint --print-config "*.*" > "C:\dev\AwesomeLabs\awesome-chat-app\eslint_settings.js"
```

Answer (score 0):

According to  the doc, You only need `eslint --print-config file.js` to make it work.  The error says the -o option you give is not a valid Path string.

Comment: Hi TsungJui.  Thanks for the response. Your answer helped me update the question to better reflect my real problem.